# Geo Ellipse ElasticSeach

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson

I know that ElasticSearch uses geoJson for geo-shape data.  It does not appear in the ElasticSearch documentation that you can have an Ellipse geo type.  However, geoJson allows for such a type.  How do you represent the Ellipse geo type in ElasticSearch?

See [here](https://github.com/geojson/geojson-spec/wiki/Proposal---Circles-and-Ellipses-Geoms) for geoJson example.

Comment: Circles and ellipses are not yet in the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html). ES supports circles, but not ellipses, yet, though.

Comment: unfortunately, for now, you will need to write (or find) the algorithm to convert your ellipse into a polygon. you will lose some accuracy in the process...

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the feedback!